# Calling a player goat

Tags: halal-haram, adab

My friend was talking about football and he said this player was the goat and I said nope and no whole smiling not because I was approving of it but because I didn't want to make it seem like I wanted to fight. (He is not Muslim) does this mean that I committed a sin? I don't approve of calling players the goats.

Answer (score 3):

The word "GOAT" when used for players in sports is used as an acronym.

It stands for **"Greatest Of All Time"**

It is not an insult but rather a form of appreciation.